# What can I do if p5 is lagging while constantly redrawing?

Tags: javascript, drawing

First of all, I'm completely new to p5.js. So I have to make some drawing functions by myself. One of them is simple line. I've got all of it figured out, it draws by dragging the mouse (gets coordinates of a click and release). The problem is that if I put it in the draw(), it starts to lag whole site because it's constantly redrawing it. Is there a way to pause a draw() function once the line is drawn and resume it when i start do draw a new one?
Here's the code:

```js
let x1s;
let x2s;
let y1s;
let y2s;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  drawLine(x1s, y1s, x2s, y2s, 255, 255, 255);
}

function putPixel(x, y, r, g, b) {
  loadPixels();
  let rgb = color(r, g, b);
  let d = pixelDensity();
  for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < d; j++) {
      // loop over
      index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));
      pixels[index] = red(rgb);
      pixels[index + 1] = green(rgb);
      pixels[index + 2] = blue(rgb);
      pixels[index + 3] = alpha(rgb);
      updatePixels();
    }
  }
}

function drawLineLow(x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b) {
  dx = x2 - x1;
  dy = y2 - y1;
  yi = 1;
  if (dy < 0) {
    yi = -1;
    dy = -dy;
  }
  D = 2 * dy - dx;
  y = y1;

  for (x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
    putPixel(x, y, r, g, b);
    if (D > 0) {
      y = y + yi;
      D = D - 2 * dx;
    }
    D = D + 2 * dy;
  }
}

function drawLineHigh(x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b) {
  dx = x2 - x1;
  dy = y2 - y1;
  xi = 1;
  if (dx < 0) {
    xi = -1;
    dx = -dx;
  }
  D = 2 * dx - dy;
  x = x1;

  for (y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    putPixel(x, y, r, g, b);
    if (D > 0) {
      x = x + xi;
      D = D - 2 * dy;
    }
    D = D + 2 * dx;
  }
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b) {
  if (abs(y2 - y1) < abs(x2 - x1)) {
    if (x1 > x2)
      drawLineLow(x2, y2, x1, y1, r, g, b);
    else
      drawLineLow(x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b);
  } else {
    if (y1 > y2)
      drawLineHigh(x2, y2, x1, y1, r, g, b);
    else
      drawLineHigh(x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  x1s = mouseX;
  y1s = mouseY;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  x2s = mouseX;
  y2s = mouseY;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems as though you need to add some logic to determine when you need to redraw, and when you don't

Answer (score 1):

As you need to redraw the line only when the coordinates of the points change, you can do it while `drawing` is `true` instead of `false`. This way the canvas will be idle when drawing is not happening and redraw happens only when it's actually required.

Additionally, `p5.js` provides basic shape drawing functions itself, so you could use `line()` to draw the line.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```js
let x1s;
let x2s;
let y1s;
let y2s;
let drawing = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  if (drawing) {
    background(0);
    stroke(255);
    line(x1s, y1s, x2s, y2s);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  x1s = x2s = mouseX;
  y1s = y2s = mouseY;
  drawing = true;
}

function mouseDragged() {
    x2s = mouseX;
    y2s = mouseY;
}


function mouseReleased() {
  drawing = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```